# Firefox issue with jquery.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have a function which retrieves a base64 encoded image from a controller and displays the image in a new window. It is working perfectly in Chrome, but fails in Firefox with the errors 'not well-formed' and 'Request method 'GET' not supported'. I don't understand why this would be the case given that I am using post, not get...

The relevant code section is:

```
function showPicture(label) {
$.post( 'picture-view', { labelname: label }, function(ImageSrc) {
   var img = new Image;
       img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + ImageSrc;
       img.style.position = 'fixed';
       img.style.left = '0';
       img.style.top = '0';
       img.onload = function() {        
       var newWindow = window.open("", label,"scrollbars=0, toolbar=0, width="+myImage.width+", height="+myImage.height);
                            creativeWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML='';
                            creativeWindow.document.documentElement.appendChild(img);
      }​
});}
```

*Edit* Also, any recommendations for accessible books or websites to learn more about this material would be gratefully received.

*Edit #2* I should also add that when I tried writing img.src to the console it came out as [objectXMLDocument].

*Edit #3* I have tracked the error down to the fact that the ImageSrc being returned should be a String but is being interpreted as an XML object. The fact that it contains back slashes is causing the 'not well-formed' error. My question is now: how do I get $.post or $.ajax to return a String in Firefox (they already do so in Chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of not leaving an unanswered question...

I ended up using a lightbox to display the image rather than generating a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Id probably try using `.ajax` instead. It'll allow you to offer fallback content too.

Rather than sending the images using post, why not host the images on your server and load the images by src. It will be a much cleaner approach.

For example

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    url: yourURL,
    error: function() {
      //The call was unsuccessful
      //Place fallback content/message here
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //The call was successful

      //Open new window
      var newWindow = window.open("", label,"scrollbars=0, toolbar=0, width="+myImage.width+", height="+myImage.height);
      creativeWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML='';

      //Create the image 
      var image = document.createElement("img");
      image.src = data;

      //Attach image to new window
      creativeWindow.document.documentElement.appendChild(image);

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice Sam. I tried using .ajax but oddly the error function is not being called.

Comment: So it would appear (evidenced when I wrote img.src to the console).

Comment: It must be something in the success function then, give me a moment to test and ill update my answer

Comment: No luck im afraid, maybe you can work something from this? -> http://jsfiddle.net/QmeHG/1/

Comment: Well thanks for trying, it's much appreciated. If it makes the problem any clearer, the issue seems to be in that the data variable does not get filled correctly. When using Chrome I get the base64 encoded image, but when using Firefox is returns as [objectXMLDocument].